# Have application stop when red X is clicked C#

Tags: c#

So my program has multiple forms, and I need a way for someone to click the X and end the program. I found Environment.exit(0) which works, except that when I'm done with the form and it closes to go on to the next one, the program ends. So I need the specific call made when the close button is clicked so that I can put the shutdown code in there. Or an equivalent suggestion so that the program can be ended from any screen. Being new to C# I'm currently using ShowDialog() to regulate the input from each form.

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

this is my current method, but activates anytime the form is closed and therefore isn't what I need. This is in Windows Form

Comment: What does your existing code look like..?

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Code added, and WinForm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Application.Exit();
```

It will close all running processes related to your application. and use

```
this.close();
```

to close your currently active form. You may call these methods in your button click event.

In your case, I suggest you to use a `bool` type variable `flag`. Make a global variable of `bool` type and name it `flag`, and when you are in that certain part where you are able to close whole application, so set `flag = true` and when you are out of that condition, set it to `false`.
Now in your form closing event, use this code:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(flag == true)
         Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Problem is, I need it to only happen when the close button is clicked, i.e. the default little red X, so I need to find that method first

Comment: Only when the X is clicked but yes. Say you get to a certain part and want to exit, you'd click the X. So I need it to end the process and not just go onto the next formwith blank data

Comment: Ah this gave me an idea which works, turns out e.CloseReason will be UserClosing if the X is pressed or None if the dialog just ends. So while this code isn't exactly what is needed the concept is correct. I'd +1 but not enough rep, thanks

Comment: Yeah ! That's also a nice solution.